# Reading multiframe tiff in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, tiff

I am trying to read a multiframe tiff of dimension 610  x 610 x 1200
`imread('file.tiff')` reads only the first image as mentioned in the documentation.

I would like to know how to read all frames.

```
ip =  imread('file.tiff')
```

i.e

```
size(ip) = 610   610
```

but I want it to return

```
size(ip) = 610  610   1200
```

Any suggestions on how to do this will be really helpful.

Comment: Your recent questions ([#1](//stackoverflow.com/q/62375730/), [#2](//stackoverflow.com/q/62042983), [#3](//stackoverflow.com/q/61716035)) seem to have received good answers. If the posted answers solve your problem, please consider [marking them accepted](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking `✓` on the left side of the answers. One answer per question can be accepted. You can also [upvote](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400) all the helpful answers if you like by clicking `▲` on the left side of the answers. This rewards the people for volunteering their time to solve your problems.

Comment: @Sardar Usama Yes of course. But sometimes I also require time to check the applicability of those answers when it's answered after a while. If I merely accept without checking the applicability, it will be less useful for the other users who look for solutions.

Comment: That's why I started the statement with "if". I am **not** asking you to accept without checking. I am just requesting you to respond to them. It has been many weeks since you posted those questions but didn't give any feedback to the people who answered which is why I mentioned that

Comment: @Sardar Usama Like I said "But sometimes I also require time to check the applicability of those answers when it's answered after a while". This was not relevant " If the posted answers solve your problem, please consider marking them accepted by clicking ✓ on the left side of the answers. One answer per question can be accepted." It's obvious that I know about it, if you had a chance to look at the questions that I've posted and accepted with bounty points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [tiff.read](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.read.html) which is dedicated for this purpose:

```
t = Tiff('file.tiff','r');
ip = read(t);
```

---

With your code, you are getting only the first image because this is the default behavior of `imread`. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#d120e615730) says:

> **TIFF Files**
> `'Index'` — Image to read
>
> `1` (default) | positive integer
> Image to read, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of `'Index'` and a positive integer. For example, if the value of `Index` is `3` then `imread` reads the third image in the file.

Also read "[Read Specific Image in Multipage TIFF File](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#btv1ptn-1_1)" in the documentation.
If you want to use `imread` then you may loop over all the indices to get your desired result.